# Remove extra white spaces on string with special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am having trouble removing extra white spaces from the following:

```
abc\ae.exe        a 1 b 2%%  ACU > log.txt
```

I am using the following code to remove extra spaces (that I found on S.O.):

```
Regex.Replace(cmdLine, @"^\s*$\n", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline).TrimEnd();
```

The above code is removing the extra white spaces between abc\ae.exe & a fine; however, it is not removing the extra white space from 2%%  ACU (has two spaces in between).

I am not very familiar with reg expressions but I am assuming it has to do with fact that the % sign might be a reg ex key word.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just replace 2 spaces with 1 space?  If it includes tab, then replace `[ \t]*` with " ".  Back-ticks seem to have a problem when just doing spaces

Comment: Hi. I am testing a line where you won't know how many spaces there will be in between various words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(cmdLine,@"\s+"," ");
```

Will replace multiple spaces with a single space

the `+` means `match the character one or more times`

Here's a [Regex Guide For C#](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am having trouble with the following string with this expression "abc\abc.exe". As you can see, if I feed this string that has no white spaces in that expression, it returns "abc bc.exe". It removes the '\a' from the string. Thanks!

Comment: In my tests it works just fine with that input, not replacing anything if there are no spaces.

Comment: That is very odd. I am not getting the following test to pass 'ingsda\test_asdsafd.exe         s 1 b 2%%           cldtg > log.txt'. It returns 'ingsda est_asdsafd.exe s 1 b 2%% cldtg > log.txt'

Comment: The problem is occuring when I add the underscore '_' in a string. That regex fail.s

Comment: Got it to work. Added the '@' in front of a string to convert it to a literal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this with [Character Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx) if you wanted to pick out specific white space characters instead of all the ones included with `\s` (Equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v]`)

```
string test = @"abc\ae.exe           a 1 b 2%%  ACU > log.txt";
// Replace one more more space characters with a single space
// Add other whitespace characters inside [ ] (ex: \t)
string no_space2 = Regex.Replace(test,@"[ ]+"," ");
```